# GHC ccall safe VS ccall unsafe

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

Dear GHC/Haskell Gurus,

I am currently writing a (medium-sized) Haskell server application using GHC, which (heavily) uses 3rd-party C library functions via the FFI. In other words, there are multiple FFI C calls made by a server thread, when serving a client request.

Currently I am calling all the C functions unsafely (**unsafe ccall**) in order to minimize the calling overhead. But the tradeoff here is, that the unsafe ccalls cannot be preemptied by the GHC RTS, meaning that all other Haskell threads are blocked until the C function returns. This could be problematic, if the C function takes too long.

On the other hand, the **safe ccalls** are more expensive but they will be run in separate OS threads and will not block the GHC's worker threads.

I guess, what I am trying to ask here is, how can you sensibly make the best choice whether to make a **safe ccall** or **unsafe ccall**? For example I don't want to make an expensive safe ccall if the C function is short and trivial, but if a C function takes long time to return (cpu-heavy computation, IO operations etc.), then making an unsafe call is problematic, since it will **block a worker thread**.
Is there a kind of approximate threshold value `t`, so that if the C function takes longer than `t` to complete, then make it a safe ccall and otherwise unsafe ccall?

I hope, this question makes somewhat sense and if there are something unclear, please don't hesitate to comment.

Thans a ton for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule of thumb is as follows:

1. Make everything `safe`.
2. If profiling reveals a performance problem in the overhead of FFI calls, carefully consider whether the semantics of `unsafe` are appropriate for the hotspot calls.
3. If profiling has revealed a performance problem in the overhead of a `safe` FFI call and semantic analysis of the call has shown that `unsafe` won't break anything, then consider a change to `unsafe` if the worst-case time of the call is expected to be better than 1 millisecond.

Don't skip the first two steps. `unsafe` has more potential issues than just blocking the RTS.

Comment: Yep, I agree with this. Mark `safe` by default, unless you have something that profiling shows to be a problem that is fixed by `unsafe`. Here is a good overview, http://blog.melding-monads.com/2011/10/24/concurrency-and-foreign-functions-in-the-glasgow-haskell-compiler/